# improve performance in huge collection

Tags: vb.net, linq, hashset

I have this code:

```
For Each Subitem In lstGastoResumen_Area
    Dim MesRealSub
    Dim MesPPTOSub

    MesRealSub = Aggregate y In lstGastoResumen Where y.Area = Subitem And y.Anio = Anio1 Into Sum(y.FebRealSoles)
    MesPPTOSub = Aggregate y In lstGastoResumen Where y.Area = Subitem And y.Anio = Anio1 Into Sum(y.FebPptoSoles)
Next
```

Where `lstGastoResumen` is a HashSet and it has more than 80,000 rows and `lstGastoResumen_Area` has 20 rows. This piece of code takes almost 20 seconds to finish.
Could anybody tell me how to improve the speed.

Comment: Is there more to the loop? it seems like you just throw away the answers...

Comment: after the loop I've saved the answers into a datatable to show them in gridview.

Comment: Do you mean in the loop? I don't see how you can save the answers outside the loop?

Comment: I created a random `lstGastoResumen` (shouldn't that be `hsGastoResumen`?) with 80,000 random objects with `Anio` distributed from 0 to 9 and `Anio1` random and ran the loop and it is taking 0.04 seconds. I don't think you are showing the code that is slow.

Comment: yes, I save the data in a datatable inside the loop. But the problem of performance is the linq part, if add another parameter in where clause, the time increase.

Comment: I saved a sql table into the collection of object: Dim lstGastoResumen As New HashSet(Of ESCG_Gasto_Resumen)(). This table has 41 columns and 80,000 rows. I don't know if I am ussing correctly the linq in hashset collection.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `HashSet` for this, you can just use a `List` but that shouldn't impact performance that much. I added an array of 40 doubles to my objects to simulate larger objects and it made little difference - I can run the code in 0.09 seconds.

Comment: What columns do you save in the `DataTable`? I added a `DataTable` ans saved the 20 rows with `Area`, `Anio`, and two `Mes`s and it still doesn't take any longer.

Comment: I have amounts for every months (january to december), and the year in another column. Additional I have a columns called Area and Gerencia. I have to calculate the amounts per year, month, Area and Gerencia. After these amounts must show in datagridview

Comment: I think you need to show more code then - your code here shouldn't be that slow.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code?  That might help identify the bottlenecks, and then you can look at the exact nature of the problem (might be an issue with an inefficient algorithm, might be the wrong data structure for your access patterns, might be something else).